# Keldysh contour and time-dependent observables

Tags: greens-functions, non-equilibrium, self-energy

1. How to use the non-equilibrium Keldysh Green's function to solve a driven harmonic oscillator?

A quantum harmonic oscillator $H_0 = \omega_0 a^\dagger a $ is coupled to a pump field E(t) (refer to the figure below),

[image: pump-probe]

The driven Hamiltonian reads, $H(t) = H_0 + E(t)(a+a^ \dagger)/\sqrt{2}$

After a delay $\Delta t$, we observe (probe ) some observables (e.g. the eneryg of the oscillator $\omega(\Delta t)$, the maximum displacement $X(\Delta t)$). How to calculated these observables by non-equilibrium Green's function?

2. What is the physics meaning of the self-energy in the non-equilibrium Green's function?

The self-energy of the non-equilibrium Green's function should have a $2\times2$ form,
$\Sigma \left(t, t^{\prime}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}\Sigma^K & \Sigma^R \\ \Sigma^A & 0\end{array}\right)\left(t, t^{\prime}\right)$, $ \Sigma ^{R/A/K}$ are rerated/advanced/Keldysh self-energy. This is quite different from the equilibrium Green's function and the corresponding self-energy $\Sigma_{eq}$. I know that the real part of $\Sigma_{eq}$ means the energy shift, and the imaginary part is means the life time. How to obtain the energy shift and lift time from the self-energy of the non-equilibrium Green's function?

3. I know that this oscillator can be solved in a classical way. Here, I want to the non-equilibrium Green's function method.